# Rewriting a hash URL FROM /

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hashtag

I have conducted a little bit of research here and have found that hashtags are client-side and can't be rewritten using .htaccess, but I think what I am trying to do is opposite of that...

I am using Ascensor.js from Kirkas.ch, which allows for a single page website with different "sections" called floors to be displayed as individual sections.

The structure is so:

```
site.com/#/floorname
site.com/#/otherfloor
site.com/#/andyetanotherfloor
```

so on and so forth.

What I am trying to do is make "permalinks" so that when someone types:

```
site.com/floorname
```

...it will be displaying the content of "site.com/#/floorname" but the browser will show "site.com/floorname" instead of the url with the hash.

Sorry if this is hard to understand. Is this possible? I have read on here that hashtags are client-side, but I think what I am trying to do is not redirect a link that is to "site.com/#/floorname" to "site.com/floorname" but the opposite.

I found this page:

which suggests that domain.com/sub/parameter

can be rewritten to:

```
domain.com/sub.html#parameter
```

But what I am trying to do is rewrite it without the sub.html page and just use the domain, using these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/      [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*       /#/%1           [R,NE,L]
```

but it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

> ...it will be displaying the content of "site.com/#/floorname" but the browser will show "site.com/floorname" instead of the url with the hash.

Not possible. The server doesn't care about the `#` fragment, the browser does. If the browser thinks it's actually going to `/floorname` and not `/#/floorname`, then the client side (Ascensor.js) isn't going to be able to render because it doesn't see a fragment. The code that you have *redirects the browser* so that it shows the URL that contains the fragment, this is something you'll have to do, there's no way to keep the fragment away from the client and expect the client to render properly.

However, this condition you have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/      [NC]
```

**will always fail**, because the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable always starts with a `/`, thus that condition will always be false.

Try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /#/$1 [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: Hi, this works great for the redirecting and thank you for helping me understand the / condition failing.

I do have one other question though, is there any way to force these filenames to lowercase? I have found that it's possible to add a RewriteMap to convert it to lowercase but I don't know how to implement it correctly. Thank you if you can help. If not, thank you for this answer as it is!

Comment: Actually, I found out that I do not have sufficient permissions to rewrite as lowercase, so this answer is sufficient to solve my problem. Thank you Jon!

Comment: @IanProvidence Yeah, you need to declare a map in the vhost or server config, can't do it in htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with some javascript. Here's an example using php + javascript but it could be done with other languages.

### /.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## we hand the fake pages and pass them into the page via querystring
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_]+)$  index.php?load_hash=$1 [L,QSA]
```

### /index.php

```
<html><head>
<?php
// then on the page, preferably high in the page, we detect the GET parameter and change the hash via javascript.
if (isset($_GET['load_hash']) && !empty($_GET['load_hash'])) {
    ?>
    <script>
    document.location.hash = '/<?php echo $_GET['load_hash'];?>';
    </script><noscript>
    <a href="#/<?php echo $_GET['load_hash'];?>">Your browser has javascript disabled. Please click here.</a>
    </noscript>
    <?php
}
?>
</head>
<body>

<script>
.. your other goes code that deals with and detects the hash tag will fire as normal if placed lower.
</script>
</body></html>
```